# MySQL: relational division - use case

Tags: mysql, relational-division

Can't seem to puzzle different kind of information together to get what I want so here goes..

Three different tables:

```
Entities
id    name
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C
```

```
Tags
id    name
 1    tag_1
 2    tag_2
 3    tag_3
```

```
Users
id    name
 1    user_1
 2    user_2
```

Both Entities:Tags and Users:Tags are 1:n relationships with both entities and users having any number of tags. There are two tables to handle those relations; entities_tags and users_tags. For example:

```
entities_tags
entity_id    tag_id
 1              1
 1              2
 2              1
 2              2
 2              3
 3              1
```

```
users_tags
user_id    tag_id
 1            1
 1            2
```

Now, given a user, I'd like to fetch all entities for which its tags are all included in the users tags. In my example user_1 should fetch entities A and C. I can fetch the user tags separately if needed, as shown below.

I've tried

```
SELECT entities.*
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(entities_tags.name SEPARATOR ', ')) AS tags
FROM entities
LEFT OUTER JOIN entities_tags ON entities_tags.entity_id = entities.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags ON tags.id = entities_tags.tag_id
WHERE tags.name IN ('tag_1','tag_2')
GROUP BY entities.id
HAVING COUNT(tags.name) = 2
```

But this would only give me both A and B and not C. I shouldn't get B, but I should get C.

Comment: Why shouldn't you get B?

Comment: @sagi: Because B has tag_3 and user_1 doesn't.